# Insertion in a Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to insert nodes in a linked list. I have tried to insert nodes at front, at the end and after a particular node. 
I think that the code is fine and should work. However, this code is giving run time error. Please explain why is it giving a run time error?

[Insertion in a linked list](http://ideone.com/AmzzSp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A linked list node
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void push(struct node* head, int new_data)
{
/* 1. allocate node */
struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

/* 2. put in the data  */
new_node->data  = new_data;

/* 3. Make next of new node as head */
new_node->next = head;

/* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
head   = new_node;
}

 /* Given a node prev_node, insert a new node after the given prev_node */
void insertAfter(struct node* prev_node, int new_data)
{
/*1. check if the given prev_node is NULL */
if (prev_node == NULL)
{
  printf("the given previous node cannot be NULL");
  return;
}

/* 2. allocate new node */
struct node* new_node =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

/* 3. put in the data  */
new_node->data  = new_data;

/* 4. Make next of new node as next of prev_node */
new_node->next = prev_node->next;

/* 5. move the next of prev_node as new_node */
prev_node->next = new_node;
}


void append(struct node* head, int new_data)
{
/* 1. allocate node */
struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

struct node *last = head;  

/* 2. put in the data  */
new_node->data  = new_data;

/* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of it as NULL*/
new_node->next = NULL;

/* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
if (head == NULL)
{
   head = new_node;
   return;
}

/* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;

/* 6. Change the next of last node */
last->next = new_node;
return;
}

// This function prints contents of linked list starting from the given node
void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
     printf(" %d ", node->data);
     node = node->next;
  }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
   /* Start with the empty list */
   struct node* head = NULL;


  append(head, 6);
  push(head, 7);
  push(head, 1);
  append(head, 4);
  insertAfter(head->next, 8);
  printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
  printList(head);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"is giving run time error"* -> Why don't you **say what the error is**?!?

Comment: Please see the ideone link. It compiles successfully but then it shows run time error. [Ideone code](http://ideone.com/AmzzSp)

Comment: Nearly anyone can get code to compile and then throw a run-time error.  Do you know that there is a development step called 'debugging'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every place you're *loosing* your `head` pointer

You should preserve its address in all functions, use `struct node**`, and update the pointer
using `*head` and `(*prev_node)`

```
void push(struct node** head, int new_data)
{ //... 
  // *head
}

void insertAfter(struct node** prev_node, int new_data)
{ //... 
  // (*prev_node)
}

void append(struct node** head, int new_data)
{ //... 
  // *head
}
```

See [*here*](http://ideone.com/tH2Ixe)

<sup>*PS:There may be logical mistake*</sup>

Also, make sure you're releasing memory using `free()` calls once you're done with everything.

Comment: But why is it necessary to give a reference to the head pointer? I've made it NULL in the main() function.

Comment: @user3087202 You need to pass the address of the `head`, what you're updating withing function is the local copy of the head pointer. `struct node** head`, signifies pointer to pointer to node, where you're suppose to pass the address of node pointer.